# use mongo auto expire feature to delete some filtered documents from a collection

Tags: database, mongodb, ttl, document-oriented-db

I have a collection named "feed"

Each document has keys called "status" and "scheduleDate" in it.

I want to set a ttl based index on scheduleDate key, but only those documents should get deleted which have

```
status:{$in:["invalid", "cancelled"]}
```

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Currently as of MongoDB 4.0, TTL indexes do not support additional field. That is, a compound TTL index is not currently supported, as mentioned in https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/#restrictions. To achieve what you require, you would need to setup an external batch process to manually delete the documents using `cron` or similar.

Comment: Even i was thinking the same that I would need to write a cron job myself. Just wanted to make sure that I did not miss anything out in the mongodb documentation. Thanks anyways.